# Unity sorting layer

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am developing a small 2d game. I have used sorting layers to my game objects. But when I add new ui text to the scene, it applies to the bottom layer of the scene. I even can not find a sorting layer option there. How can I bring the ui text to front. Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends, it could be that you have your canvas set to a particular render mode. So try clicking on the canvas and where it has a drop down menu called render mode select screen-space camera, attach your camera to it and then set your sorting layers from there until you get what you need. Should work with 'World Space' as well. Hope that helps.